# How to add Point Cloud Model to Viewer in Autodesk Forge

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, point-cloud-library

I recently followed the tutorial and added Forge Viewer and am looking to take it forward.
Currently, I am looking for a method to add a Custom Extension to load a point cloud model to Forge Viewer

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below sample to load Point cloud file.

If Point cloud size is small (up to 1 million points) then you can go with solution no. 1. Otherwise you can follow solution no. 2 for the big point cloud file.

1. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-point-clouds-forge-viewer
2. https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo